# Facebook Beta Push Notifications Campaigns not delivering

Tags: ios, facebook

I've set up Push Notifications in FB Analytics and was able to send the Setup Verification to a specific device and got it. (ie: APN certs etc are set up properly)

However, when I create a campaign and schedule it, nothing. The details of how many devices should receive it are correct, 2 devices, but those devices do not get anything and in fact the FB PN screen shows 0 delivered.

(Does anyone know the best place to ask questions regarding FB SDK for iOS beta features? It's not obvious in the FB Dev area.)

Thanks!

Comment: Did you got any solution for this. I am facing same problem.

Comment: Same here. I'd love to get an answer to this.